# Java EE Web App - Image path configuration

Tags: html, image, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have implemented image upload feature but I am facing issue with its path configuration.

I want to store the uploaded the images outside of webapp root directory because every time I un-deploy the application, it deletes the images within the application.

Now, I can store the the uploaded file by getting the path from property file [say C:\images] but when I use that path in  it doesn't show the file in web page.

Can you please let me know how to get the absolute path in img src tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't reference files outside of the webapp root.  You're going to need to use virtual directories.  These will map outside paths into accessible URLs so c:\images will be accessible as myapp.com/myapp/images/

This sort of thing is specific to the application server you are running, so you'll need to check the documentation for your system to make this work.

Comment: I have found following link for glass-fish: http://harkiran-howtos.blogspot.sg/2009/08/map-external-directory-into-glassfish.html?showComment=1364783965423#c8018115331866149599

Comment: I also did tomcat configuration - http://harkiran-howtos.blogspot.sg/2009/08/map-external-directory-into-your.html